# What is the rank and date of this Italian Army uniform?

Tags: identification, uniform, italian

This a photo of my uncle from Cosenza, Italy. I believe it was taken around 1910. I would like to confirm a more accurate date range, as well as his rank. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_ranks_of_the_Kingdom_of_Italy#Enlisted_-_Army seems to indicate "Sergente maggiore" .  (Going by the stripes at the cuff.)

Comment: @kimchilover I think is more likely "Sergente".

Comment: @effedici  You might be right.  On re-looking, I see one black loopless chevron below a looped chevron. Perhaps I was confused by what I thought was a white chevron below the black one